# Question About Direct Sum.

Tags: linear-algebra

There's a question in my textbook that I attempted to solve, I got half of it. I couldn't get the other half.

The question is:
Let $U$ be a subspace of dimension $k$ of a vector space $W$ of dimension $n$. Prove that there exists a subspace $V$ of dimension $n - k$ such that $W = V \bigoplus W$.

My proof was:

Let $\left\{u_1,..., u_k\right\}$ be a basis for U. We can then extend this basis to be $\left\{u_1,...,u_k,v_{k+1}, ..., v_n\right\}$ to be a basis for W.

From this, let $V$ = $span(v_{k+1}, ..., v_n)$.

We want to show that using this subspace V, we can construct the direct sum $W = V \bigoplus W$.

So we want to show that: $W = U+V$ and $U \cap V =$ $\left\{0\right\}$.

To prove the first part, let $w$ be in $W$ and show that $w$ can be written at $u+v$

Since $span(u_1, ..., u_k, v_{k+1}, ..., v_n)$ = $W$, we can write $w$ as $a_1u_1 + ... + a_ku_k + a_{k+1}v_k + ... + a_nv_n$, where $a_i$ $\in F$. But this is exactly $w = u + v$ since $U = span(u_1, ..., u_k)$ and $V = span(v_{k+1}, ..., v_n)$. Thus $w = u + v$

I'm now stuck trying  $U \cap V =$ $\left\{0\right\}$. I had an idea to prove this by contradiction (but I'm not sure if it's correct).

Suppose that the  $U \cap V \neq$ $\left\{0\right\}$. That mean there exist a vector $x$ such that $x$ $\in U$ and $x \in V$. That means that $U = span(u_1, ..., x, ..., u_k)$ and $V = span(v_{k+1}, ..., x, ..., v_n)$. i.e. $W = span(u_1, ..., u_k, v_{k+1}, ..., x, ..., v_{n})$. But this is clearly a contradiction because if this was the case, then the dimension of $W$ would be $n-1$.

Is this okay? Sorry for such a silly question.

Comment: But $x$ cannot be a basis vector, since it is a linear combination of the other basis vectors, so Basis $\cup${$x$} is not a linearly-independent set.

Answer (score 0):

The problem I see with your argument is that if $x$ is in the span of a basis $B_U$  of some suspace $U$, then $B_U \cup $ {$x$} is not a linearly-independent set: if $$c_1v_1+...+c_kv_k=x $$ , then $$c_1v_1+c_2v_2+....+(-1)x=0 $$ is a non-trivial linear combination of  $B_U \cup $ {$x$} that equals $0$.

A possible different argument is this:
Assume the two spans overlap;let {$v_1,..,v_k$} extend into a basis {$v_1,v_2,...,v_k,v_{k+1},...,v_m$} and assume $$c_1v_1+...+c_kv_k =w= c_{k+1}v_{k+1}+...+c_mv_m $$. Now you can subtract the two linear combinations that equal $w$, to get a new linear combination of  $m$ basis vectors: $$c_1v_1+c_2v_2+...-(c_{k+1}v_{k+1}+...+c_mv_m)= c_1v_1+c_2v_2+...-c_{k+1}v_{k+1}-...-c_mv_m =0$$, where the $c_i$ are not all $0$, and get a contradiction in an m-dimensional vector space....